# Efficient way to find paths from a list of filenames

Tags: bash, shell, find

From a list of file names stored in a file `f`, what's the best way to find the relative path of each file name under `dir`, outputting this new list to file `p`? I'm currently using the following:

```
while read name
do
    find dir -type f -name "$name" >> p
done < f
```

which is too slow for a large list, or a large directory tree.

EDIT: A few numbers:

- Number of directories under `dir`: 1870
- Number of files under `dir`: 80622
- Number of filenames in `f`: 73487

All files listed in `f` do exist under `dir`.

Comment: So your file contains a list of filenames with no path information? How do you want to handle files that appear multiple times? I assume you'll want to load the entire directory tree into memory to do this quickly as repeatedly scanning the disk is never going to be fast enough but whether that's viable depends on the size we're talking about. I'm afraid I don't know the bash-esque way to do this but doing it in PHP or similar would be trivial if that's an option?

Comment: Yes, just the filenames, and the result must include all possible paths. It's okay to load the directory tree onto memory, but I'd rather not use PHP, as it's not installed. Perl or Python are ok though.

Comment: +1 for using `while read name ... done < f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following piece of python code does the trick. The key is to run find once and store the output in a hashmap to provide an O(1) way to get from file_name to the list of paths for the filename.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

file_names = open("f").readlines()
file_paths = os.popen("find . -type f").readlines()
file_names_to_paths = {}
for file_path in file_paths:
    file_name = os.popen("basename "+file_path).read()
    if file_name not in file_names_to_paths:
        file_names_to_paths[file_name] = [file_path]
    else:
        file_names_to_paths[file_name].append(file_path) # duplicate file

out_file = open("p", "w")
for file_name in file_names:
    if file_names_to_paths.has_key(file_name):
        for path in file_names_to_paths[file_name]:
            out_file.write(path)
```

Comment: Why not use `os.path.walk` and `os.path.basename(file_path)`?

Comment: os.path.basename, in special, must be used. It fails when `file_path` contains spaces

Comment: 4 seconds, no missing files. If nothing shorter shows up, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this perl one-liner

```
perl -e '%H=map{chomp;$_=>1}<>;sub R{my($p)=@_;map R($_),<$p/*> if -d$p;($b=$p)=~s|.*/||;print"$p\n" if$H{$b}}R"."' f
```

1- create an hashmap whose keys are filenames : %H=map{chomp;$_=>1}<>

2- define a recursive subroutine to traverse directories : sub R{}

2.1- recusive call for directories : map R($_), if -d$p

2.2- extract the filename from the path : ($b=$p)=~s|.*/||

2.3- print if hashmap contains filename : print"$p\n" if$H{$b}

3- call R with path current directory : R"."

EDIT : to traverse hidden directories (.*)

```
perl -e '%H=map{chomp;$_=>1}<>;sub R{my($p)=@_;map R($_),grep !m|/\.\.?$|,<$p/.* $p/*> if -d$p;($b=$p)=~s|.*/||;print"$p\n" if$H{$b}}R"."' f
```

Comment: Nice and fast, but for some reason it misses a few files

Comment: is it because filename can contain pattern like * ?

Comment: Nope. In fact, I can see no pattern on the missing file names, and I can confirm they do exist and are listed.

Comment: It is running for two minutes now, and no match at all

Comment: normally `grep !m|/\.\.?$|,` filters `.` and `..` otherwise process may loop

Comment: Still, the same files are missing, and it also includes some directories.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
xargs locate -b < f | grep ^dir > p
```

**Edit**: I can't think of an easy way to prefix `dir/*/` to the list of file names, otherwise you could just pass that directly to `xargs locate`.

Comment: `locate` use arguments as partial matches, and prints absolute filenames. `awk '{print "\\" $0}' f | xargs -d '\n' locate -b | sed "s|$(pwd)/||g" | grep ^dir > d` will possibly do the trick.

Comment: Ah yes, those partial matches, my prefix idea doesn't have that problem but it does of course have the problem of not finding `dir/$file`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what percentage of the directory tree is considered a match, it might be faster to find *every* file, then grep out the matching ones:

```
find "$dir" -type f | grep -f <( sed 's+\(.*\)+/\1$+' "$f" )
```

The `sed` command pre-processes your list of file names into regular expressions that will only match full names at the end of a path.

Comment: Left this running for a few minutes with no output at all. Timing each component shows that grep is the culprit, and, given the fact that grep outputs matches as soon as it finds one, I don't think this is faster than my naïve approach.

Comment: Too bad. I thought even with a long list of file names, a single `grep` might be faster than many calls to `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using bash and grep

```
#!/bin/bash

flist(){
for x in "$1"/*; do #*/ for markup
[ -d "$x" ] && flist $x || echo "$x"
done
}

dir=/etc #the directory you are searching
list=$(< myfiles) #the file with file names

#format the list for grep
list="/${list//
/\$\|/}"

flist "$dir" | grep "$list"
```

...if you need full posix shell compliance (busybox ash, hush, etc...) replace the $list substring manipulation with a variant of chepner's sed and replace $(< file) with $(cat file)

Comment: The problem with chepner's method wasn't on the speed of `find`, but of `grep`, which isn't fixed in your version, and which also contains two problems of its own: `find dir -type f` is reimplemented for no reason, and `grep "$list"` will overflow the limits on command-line arguments length